# Instagram ?__a=1 json get page 2

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I get json of instagram with url:

```
https://www.instagram.com/xxx/?__a=1
```

If I want get page 2, I have end_cursor but not work for me:

```
https://www.instagram.com/xxx/?__a=1&end_cursor=...
https://www.instagram.com/xxx/?__a=1&hash=...
https://www.instagram.com/xxx/?__a=1&page=2
https://www.instagram.com/xxx/?__a=1&after=...
```

How I can access page 2?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user190794 yes i use api